# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in parseJSON method javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In a webpage that uses javascript, I pass data to a hidden input field using

```
$("#waypt_sel").val(JSON.stringify(itins.arr_intin));
```

and then later access that data using

```
waypts_input = $.parseJSON($("#waypt_sel").val())
```

This works, except that sometimes it gives a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

. I tracked the error to this line with the json parsing. but I am baffled because this works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't for the same, identical string.

I checked the values that are passed to the html inputs and it works and doesn't work for the same values. 
Here's an example of the json  string I am passing:

```
"[{\"location\":\"8.3353156, 80.3329846\",\"stopover\":true}, {\"location\":\"8.0326424, 80.7446666\",\"stopover\":true}, {\"location\":\"7.9577778, 80.667518\",\"stopover\":true}, {\"location\":\"7.953208, 81.006675\",\"stopover\":true}, {\"location\":\"7.885949, 80.651479\",\"stopover\":true},{\"location\":\"7.2905425, 80.5986581\",\"stopover\":true},{\"location\":\"7.300322, 80.386362\",\"stopover\":true}]"
```

Here's the structure of the code I use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.ajax({
        url: "aa.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: selected_i
        },
        success: function(result) {

            itins = $.parseJSON(result);
            $("#waypt_sel").val(JSON.stringify(itins.arr_intin));
        }
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "dd.php",

        success: function(result) {
            locations = $.parseJSON(result);
            initializeMap();

        }
    });


    function initializeMap() {
    //other code
        calculateAndDisplayRoute();
//other code


        function calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
            //other code
            waypts_input = $.parseJSON($("#waypt_sel").val());
            waypts_json_input = $.parseJSON(waypts_input);
            //other code
            }

    }


});
```

And here is the detailed error message I get on firefox developer edition browser.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data
>
> calculateAndDisplayRoute()    map.js:366
>
> initializeMap()          map.js:290
>
> .success()         map.js:62
>
> m.Callbacks/j()    jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
>
> m.Callbacks/k.fireWith()  jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
>
> x()              jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5
>
> .send/b()       jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of `JSON.stringify(itins.arr_intin)`?

Comment: Show the code, show the json, make a working snippet/fiddle. See more: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ We aren't wizards with crystal balls.

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer the question, but why don't you store the value in a simple javascript variable?

Comment: "*I am baffled because this works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't for the same, identical string.*" - I can't really believe that.

Comment: Put some `timeout` between setter and getter..might do the trick!

Comment: @Bergi I checked the values in the input variable when the parsing failed and succeeeded and it was the same. i found it really hard to believe too, sometimes the waypoints would work and show the route , sometimes it won't.

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kxfvnk1g/. You need to debug this to ensure that the code is being executed after the request has completed, and also that the response is *exactly* what you expect it to  be.

Comment: Also curious why you are using `JSON.stringify` in one place, and `$.parseJSON` somewhere else - why not use `JSON.parse` as well as it's part of the standard library?

Comment: I added the code structure, if it would help.

Comment: `JSON.parse` works fine in the fiddle given by @RoryMcCrossan. You can give a try with `eval(JSON.parse(json_string))`

Comment: Added error message I got in firefox.

Comment: Why dont you just pass the variable in a value? Now that BAFFLES me!

Comment: @RayonDabre I tried setTimeout, but it didn't dekay the execution of script somehow.

Comment: @Bergi  my test page is **voyate.xitech.com.au**, can you have a look, when you load an itinerary, the map route should work, but it doesn't work always. only sometimes. Please select an itinerary from the bottom 3 in the list

Comment: @NisalUpendra: I've tried and only have seen that you access `.json_day_data` where it should have been `.day_data`; so you pass `null` instead of some JSON (and subsequently your script fails). I've also managed to get an (unreproducable) SQL exception `" <br /> <b>Warning</b>: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: &quot; &quot; LINE 1: SELECT * FROM itineraries WHERE id=' ^ in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\tourismapp_test\getselecteditin2.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br /> Cannot execute query: SELECT * FROM itineraries WHERE id=' ' "` that was attempted to be parsed.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the explainaition. It put me in the right direction. the issue, as you suggested is because the sql query 'sometimes' returns empty. Trying to figure out why this happens only sometimes. It could be the ajax query or a server error with php. Will checkk

Comment: @nagylzs thank you for the brilliant suggestion. This made the code less complex, but didnt fix the issue, which seems to be caused by something else

Comment: Well, if you can store it in a simple variable then there is no need to call stringify/serialize at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using an asynchronous ajax request to retrieve json data. by the time the data had been retrieved and pasted to the html, the execution of the code that used the html data had happened, and thus gave an error. I used a callback function for the ajax query and this did the job.

```
function get_det(callback) {//Your asynchronous request.  
    $.ajax({
      url: "aa.php",
      type: "POST",
      success: function (result) {
        alert("1st call");
        callback();//invoke when get response 
      }
    });
  }
```

and in the code where this is called:

```
get_det(secondFunction);//calling with callback function
function secondFunction()//your callback function
{
 alert("2nd Call");
}
```

Alternatively you may also try `async: false` in the ajax query parameters. But this can cause browser freezing and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

"\" is unnecessary when deserialize json string  in javascript .

what json tools you used?

you serialize in one tool , and deserialize with other , may get this scene .

Comment: ``\`` is just part of the string literal.

Comment: This is because the this json array is part of a larger another json array. Need to escape double quotes when using json arrays inside json arrays, else it gave me errors

Comment: @NisalUpendra: Well in that case it's really an antipattern. Don't put JSON in JSON strings inside JSON.